# Loading and displaying dataframes from multiple files in python

Tags: python, file, pandas

I am trying to read in multiples files from a directory and assign it to different variables using for loop. When I run the script it doesn't output any results:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
os.chdir("~pathtodirectory")
file1="baseball.csv"
file2="baseball1.csv"
output=dict()
x=0
for file in [file1,file2]:
    output[x]=pd.read_csv(file)
    output[x].head()
    x=+1
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't output any results? You aren't printing anything, so you shouldn't see anything in the terminal. What, exactly, *were you expecting* and what, exactly, did you not see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should be using `enumerate`. Secondly, you should be calling `print`.

```
for i, file in enumerate([file1, file2]):
    output[i] = pd.read_csv(file)
    print(output[i].head())   # <------------
```

---

If your keys are going to be indices, why not just use a list instead?

```
output = []
for file in [file1, file2]:
    output.append(pd.read_csv(file))
    ...
```